# Ionic 2 Native Linkedin UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I trying to setup the ionic 2 native component for Linkedin as described here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/linkedin/

but when i do:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/linkedin
```

I receive:

```
ionic-hello-world@ /home/gx/ionic2/linkTest
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.1.0
└── @ionic-native/linkedin@3.1.1 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic-native/linkedin@3.1.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@3.1.1 but none was installed.
```

here my env info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v4.2.6
Xcode version: Not installed
```

how can I solve? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update your `ionic-native` version to [`3.1.0`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310-2017-03-20)
Check package.json [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json#L22).
Add an entry `"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",` to your package.json and remove your old entry.
Now run `npm install`.
Clear `node_modules` folder if it does not work.

Comment: the required core version is 3.1.1
so I solve changing in my package.json
`
"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
`
to

`
"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.1",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.1",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.1",
`
removing the node_modules folder and running `npm install`

Comment: `├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.1.0` your log says 3.1.0...

Answer (score 2):

The Ionic team has released the [**latest Ionic Native 3.x**](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-native-3-x/).Hence to avoid above issue you have to create your app using latest CLI.In other words you have to create new V2 project.That is it.Good luck!

```
 ionic start myfirstapp blank --v2
```